# Mongoose create child and associated parent at same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So basically, in my application I have a employee, and a company model. This is just the basic information about these models, there is actually more information, so using nested objects rather than 2 schema's doesn't seem like a good option (I think)

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', required: true },
  }
);
```

```
var CompanySchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  },
);

CompanySchema.virtual('employees', {
  ref: 'Employee',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'company',
  justOne: false,
});
```

And on a form to create a new employee, I want the option to either select a company, or create a new one.

So my API will send information like the following:

```
employee: {
  name: 'John Bastien',
  company: 5d44635fa5993c0424da8e07
}
```

or:

```
employee: {
  name: 'Dan Smith',
  company: {
     name: 'ACME'
  }
}
```

This of course can be changed, it was just what I had in mind.

So in my express app when I do `var employee = await new Employee(req.body.employee).save();` How can I make it so that the company is created along with the employee. It works fine when sending an object ID, but how can I do it with just a JSON object for the associated document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some middleware on my models that will handle this. This logic could be extracted out to make it more generic, but for my use case it hasn't needed to yet.

```
EmployeeSchema.virtual('company', {
  ref: 'Company',
  localField: 'companyId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
}).set(function(company) {
  this.companyId= company._id;
  this.$company = company;
  return this.$company;
});

EmployeeSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  if (this.company && this.company instanceof Company) {
    var err = this.company.validateSync();
    if (err) {
      // mergeErrors is a helper function that will merge the two exceptions into a nice format
      err = mergeErrors(this.validateSync(), { company: err });
    }

    next(err);
  }
  next();
});

EmployeeSchema.pre('save', async function(next, saveOpts) {
  if (this.company && this.company instanceof Company && this.company.isModified()) {
    await this.company.save(saveOpts);
  }
  next();
});
```